# C# numbers and Letters

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need my application to perform an action based on if the selected text is contains letters or anything except numbers dont do that.

How can I tell if a string is letters or numbers?

Its so easy but i can not write this code.

Comment: Be more specific please, do you want to find out if it only contains letters or if it only contains numbers?

Comment: @atticae - Hard to tell, but among our answers he will probably find something he can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do it like this:

```
string myString = "100test200";
long myNumber;
if( long.TryParse( myString, out myNumber ){
  //text contains only numbers, and that number is now put into myNumber.
  //do your logic dependent of string being a number here
}else{
  //string is not a number. Do your logic according to the string containing letters here
}
```

If you want to see if the string contains **one or more** digits, and not all digits, use this logic instead.

```
if (myString.Any( char.IsDigit )){
  //string contains at least one digit
}else{
  //string contains no digits
}
```

Comment: long.Parse will fail if the number is larger than 2^63

Comment: @Manu - If that is the case, he can use my second approach. My first approach is good if he actually needs to use the number for anything, and I guess he does since he is trying to figure out of there is a letter inside his number or not :)

Comment: Thank you . It was what im looking for . But there is another problem if myString is fraction it thinks that it is letter.

Comment: sorry i wanted to say if it is not integer

Comment: @Acid - I'm not 100% sure what you mean here. Can you give me an example string, and what you need the result to be, then I'll help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
static bool IsNumeric(string str)
{
  foreach(char c in str)
    if(!char.IsDigit(c))
       return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Or `str.All(char.IsDigit);` for short ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve this with a regular expression

```
string str = "1029";
if(Regex.IsMatch(str,@"^\d+$")){...}
```